# Windows 10 Font folder displaying as files instead of fonts

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, fonts, control-panel

I do not know why but opening C:\Windows\Fonts leads to this view:

[image]

when I know I should be getting this: [image]

Is there something wrong with my Windows 10 install? I just did a fresh installation yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder has either lost its `desktop.ini` file or the folder's `ReadOnly` attribute has been cleared, which means its `desktop.ini` file won't be processed.

- Open the `C:\Windows` folder in a `Details` view.
- Add the `Attributes` column.
- Verify that an `R` is displayed for the **`Fonts`** folder.

[image]

If it's not set, open a **PowerShell** window to `C:\WIndows` and execute the command:

- `(gi Fonts).Attributes += 'ReadOnly'`

If that doesn't fix the issue, check the contents of the `desktop.ini` file:

- In the **PowerShell** window, execute the follwoing:
- `notepad c:\Windows\Fonts\desktop.ini`

The contents should be as follows:
[image]

If the file doesn't exist, create it. Set its attributes to `Hidden` and `System`:

**PowerShell**:

```
@'
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID={BD84B380-8CA2-1069-AB1D-08000948F534}

'@ | sc c:\Windows\Fonts\desktop.ini -Force

(gi c:\Windows\Fonts\desktop.ini).Attributes += 'System'
(gi c:\Windows\Fonts\desktop.ini).Attributes += 'Hidden'
```

Comment: Perfect, all the way up to the desktop.ini not existing. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the icon size from drop down menu at bottom right from small to large.

Comment: This does not group it by font family/collection though

Comment: sort them alphabaticaly